# how to customization of android Home Screen by changing in source code of android 2.3

Tags: android, replace, homescreen

here i want to launch Android Home Screen

Can anybody tell me where to find information about how to write a custom home-screen application? and i want to remove android default home screen. and add my custom home screen code to source of android.

So very first i have to make application which launch as a home screen so any body can give me some tips or guidelines?

Thanks

Comment: Historically, StackOverflow has not been a great resource for firmware questions. You might consider visiting http://source.android.com, clicking on the Community tab, finding a relevant Google Group, and asking there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to customization of android Home Screen?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033458/how-to-customization-of-android-home-screen)

Answer (score 0):

create a home application , which is nothing but an application with home intent . Samples (../android-sdk-linux/samples/android-8) have a good example named "Home" .

once app install when user will click on homeScreen he will be prompted for select home among existing home apps (including your app too) , once user set it as default this will not be asked again .

Comment: but can i change this things in default android source code and launch my own home screen? Because i have to first customize the home screen and than built code on some processor or evolution board. so this thing possible by this way. i can change main source code and replace my own home screen code.

Comment: are you working at framework layer ? because at application layer we dont have access to android source code , our worked bounded by API support for third party apps , so cant do this . but at framework level to replace default home app should work .

Comment: Yes i want to do this things on Framwork layer. i complete my customization of home screen so how can i add this things on Android Source and and replace Android default home screen code?